# SSE (SIMD) Scalar-vector multiplication GCC 8

Tags: gcc, sse, intrinsics

I just found out, looking as some code I wrote a few months ago, that I had a multiplication and addition using mixed types such as :

```
__m128 = float + __m128 * (__m128 - float)
```

However, neither GCC8 nor LLVM6 ever complained and the output looked as expected.

Replacing the float by what should go there (`_mm_set1_ps(float)`) seems to be slower to compute (in a loop where the float is set every iteration).

What's going on there ? Is the first version safe (portable/compatible) ? (This code has been in production for a couple of months, nobody complained).

Comment: Code like this wouldn't compile with MSVC, but it often needs slightly different treatment anyway

Comment: Do you have a [mcve] for the slowdown, so we can look at the compiler-generated asm?  Possibly with more intrinsics and less GNU C native vector syntax might have resulted in different asm.  Like maybe it was distributing the multiply inside the parens, and doing `float - __m128*float + __m128*__m128` with two broadcast-loads and two FMAs (if you compiled with `-march=haswell` or Bulldozer/Ryzen), and it isn't doing that with `set1`.  Or maybe it's just using different shuffles to broadcast for `set1` vs. GNU C native vector syntax, for some reason.  Obviously a missed optimization somewhere.